# XeLaTeX: lost \perp in Cambria math?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, unicode-math

Occasionally I noted that `Cambria Math` fonts or the `unicode-math` package might have wrong definition of `\perp` math symbol. Attached picture shows that `\perp` is not printed properly while `\bot` is.

[image]

This test is produced by the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
\ifpdf
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % source file encoding
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % cyrillic font encoding
\fi

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        %\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
        \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
        \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\fi
\begin{document}%
    \[
        p_{\perp}
        ,\qquad
        \vec{A} \perp \vec{B}
    \]
    \[
        p_{\bot}
        ,\qquad
        \vec{A} \bot \vec{B}
    \]
\end{document}
```

The missing character is reported in the log file:

```
Missing character: There is no вџ‚ in font Cambria Math/ICU:script=math;languag
e=DFLT;+ssty=0;!
Missing character: There is no вџ‚ in font Cambria Math/ICU:script=math;languag
e=DFLT;!
 [1]
```

This same file can be conditionally compiled with both `xelatex` and `pdflatex` just to check that standard fonts use same glyph to print both `\bot` and `\perp`. So, I guess that error may reside in the `unicode-math` package. Could somebody check is this guess correct?

I would also appreciate any advice how to redefine the `\perp` command to make it working for a while before the problem will be corrected by the font/package developers.

Comment: BTW, `\ifpdf` is misused here since it does not check for pdftex but rather for `\pdfoutput` value so it will be true with luatex and false with pdftex/luatex in dvi mode, which is not really what you want. So `\ifxetex ... \else ... \fi` is more appropriate in this case (you may also check for luatex if you want to support it too).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The character in question is U+27C2, which doesn't exist in Cambria Math. In this case you should use `\mathrel\bot` instead (the `\mathrel` is necessary to get the spacing right).

As a long-term solution we should implement fall-back characters in `unicode-math`. U+27C2 is intended for the perpendicular relation as indicated by Unicode; MathML, on the other hand, suggests to use U+22A5 for that purpose. Currently `\perp` is hard-wired to map to U+27C2, and `\bot` maps to U+22A5. The correct solution would be to have `\perp` map to U+22A5 if U+27C2 is not available. I'll add that to the issue tracker, but I have no time to look after it during the next couple of weeks.

Comment: May I remind this your promise. `\perp` is not printed still altough I am using the most recent version of miktex.

Comment: Working Cambria Math in 2017, I would also like to bring this promise back to the fore.