# Difference of perp and bot

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I saw in *math.stackexchange* that someone uses `\perp` for what I always use `\bot`.
In [XeLaTeX: lost \perp in Cambria math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/xelatex-lost-perp-in-cambria-math) it says that they are two different symbols, do they just look the same?

I guess the spacing is different like in `\Longleftrightarrow` and in `\iff`, which one should be used in math?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bot}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\perp}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"3F}
```

So they use the same glyph from the same font but `\perp` gets the spacing for an infix *relation* like `<` whereas `\bot` is a mathord so gets no special spacing, like a letter `x`.

So either can be used in math, depending on the intended meaning.

Comment: For the semantics: I use `\perp` for "Perpendicular" and `\bot` for "bottom" (a contradiction in logic).

Comment: Also `\not\perp` looks good but `\not\bot` does not.