# Is there a better (more condensed) way of formatting a subscript \perp (or \bot)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, typography

I'm writing a lot of these types of formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol k_\bot \cdot \boldsymbol r_\bot}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In which the perpendicular symbol takes quite some space, which makes the equation less readable. Is there a simple way to either do this better, or make the `\perp` symbol smaller for this case? The less hackish the better, but I understand this is latex :-)

Comment: I know what B.S. is, but what is `\bs`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: `\bs` = `\boldsymbol` ? (At least it is my short macro for that ;-))

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: use a `\!` after the `\bot` for a small backspace.

Comment: @rubenvb: Perhaps `\perp` might help

Comment: @Christian `\perp` is just `\mathrel{\bot}`. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102187/174). I made the example self-contained :).

Comment: @rubenvb: It was just an idea, I did not track down every remapping of commands ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here, I really squeeze it with a `\!` to the left of the `\bot` and two to the right.  As a less intense version, a single `\!` to the right would do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mybot{{\!\bot\!\!}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol k_\mybot \cdot \boldsymbol r_\mybot}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the less intense version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mybot{{\bot\!}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol k_\mybot \cdot \boldsymbol r_\mybot}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, taking Heiko's suggestion, which carries great weight on this site, of placing a single `\!` on either side of the `\bot` produces the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mybot{{\!\bot\!}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol k_\mybot \cdot \boldsymbol r_\mybot}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\cdot` is a binary operator; I do not think, it should be too close to the left operand, thus I prefer one `\!` on both sides each.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\def\Bot{\scriptscriptstyle\kern-1pt\bot\kern-1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \bm k_{\Bot}\!\cdot \bm r_{\Bot}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]